# Formulario de contacto distinto por cada elemento listado

Tags: php, mysql

Me explico, necesito un formulario de contacto distinto para cada usuario cuando entra a una categoría.

Es decir, la web es de anuncios clasificados, y los anuncios están listados por categorías, necesito un botón contactar que se repita dentro del bucle while que muestra los anuncios, los anuncios están en una tabla mysql, la cual contiene el email del anunciante en cada registro.

El problema es crear el formulario dentro del while, con cada destinatario diferente.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Hola Maseres, para poder entender tu pregunta, como mínimimo,debes incluir el código que provee contexto a la pregunta.

Comment: Te recomiendo que visites [ask], para saber como preguntar y te que visites [tour]

Answer (score 1):

Teniendo un caso así:

```
|id_anuncio|email_usuario|
|----1-----|email@dom.com|
|----2-----|email@dom.com|
|----3-----|email@dom.com|
```

En tu código deberías ejecutar un bucle como siempre, por ejemplo si usas mysqli sería algo así:

```
$conn = new mysqli("parametros de coneción");
$consulta = $conn -> query("SELECT * FROM table");
if( $consulta ){
while($obj = $consulta -> fetch_object()){
?>
<!-- tu codigo normal del anuncio a mostrar, imagen, descripción etc, etc -->

<form method="POST" action="/?page=product_list"><!-- aqui envias a la página que procesará la petición POST -->
<input type="hidden" name="clave" value="contacto"> <!-- un identificador para que sepas que acción debe realizarse -->
<input type="hidden" name="id_anuncio" value="<?php echo $obj -> id_anuncio; ?>"> <!-- el identificador del anuncio, este se enviará a tu script de procesamiento, allá deberás hacer otra consulta a la base de datos para obtener el correo -->
<button type="submit">Contactar al anunciante</button>
</form>
<!-- puede existir más codigo de este lado, el formulario solo mostrará un botón -->
<?php
}
}
```

No es buena práctica agregar correos directamente en un formulario ya que existen scripts (BOTS) que recolectan correos para listas de spam.

Esto es en dos partes, acá en este ejemplo envías el identificador del anuncio a un script que obtendrá por método POST los valores del formulario entre ellos el identificador. Éste tendrá que obtener por medio de una consulta al la base de datos el correo que corresponde a dicho id, de ahí hacer cualquier cosa con el.

Ejemplo:

```
if($_POST["clave"] === "contacto" && is_numeric($_POST["id_anuncio"])){
<!-- Acá la conexión a la base de datos en una variable ($conn en este ejemplo) -->
$result = $conn -> query("select email_usuario from anuncios where id_anuncio = ".(int)$_POST["id_anuncio"]); <!-- No uses esto tal cual, es mala practica de seguridad, hay que sanear el valor -->
if( $result ){
$obj = $result -> fetch_object();
<!-- $obj ahora tiene el correo electronico correspondiente al identificador que se obtuvo de la consulta, ahora se puede hacer lo que quieras con el -->
}
```

Comment: No es mala idea, pero yo tengo creado un popup creado en javascript, lo que quiero es que el formulario no se procese en otra página, sino que al igual que milanuncios, directamente se procesa en el mismo javascript, es decir, el envio de email se procesa en el mismo popup. tengo creado el boton que abre ese popup y se repite dentro de la sentencia While, pero para coger el correo en sí, no sé como hacerlo... Gracias amigo

Comment: Necesitas ajax, para lo cual es lo mismo que el ejemplo anterior.
No puedes enviar correos(Que yo sepa) desde javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Tengo esto:

```
    while ($array = mysql_fetch_array($cad)){
    <div>

    //muestro los resultados de los anuncios
    <div id="abc1">
<!-- Popup Div Starts Here -->
<div id="popupContact1">
<!-- Contact Us Form -->
        <a onclick="contacto1()"><button onClick="form6.reset();" id="submit1" style="float:right">Contactar</button></a>
        <form action="" id="form6" name="form6" autocomplete="off" method="post">
    <fieldset>
    <legend style="font-size: 16pt;"><b>Contactar con el anunciante</b></legend>
                <img id="close" src="/images/x.png" onclick ="div_hide1()" width="10" height="10">
                <?php if (isset($array["nombre"]) && $array["nombre"] != ""){ ?>
                <div>Nombre anunciante: <em style="color:#CCFFFF;"><?php echo utf8_encode($array["nombre"]); ?></em></div>
                <?php } ?>
                <?php if (isset($contactito["telefono"]) && $contactito["telefono"] != ""){ ?>
                <div><b>Teléfono: <a href="tel://<?php echo utf8_encode($array["telefono"]); ?>"   style="color:#006600;"><?php echo utf8_encode($array["telefono"]); ?></a></b></div><br>
                <?php } ?> 
                <label>Enviar mensaje al correo del anunciante</label><br>
                <label><strong>Tu email:</strong></label><br />
                <input type="email" placeholder="email" name="email" id="email" tabindex="1" required autocomplete="off" /><br /><br />
                <label><strong>Tu nombre:</strong></label><br />
                <input type="text" placeholder="Nombre" name="nombre" tabindex="2" autocomplete="off" /><br /><br />
                <label><strong>Mensaje:</strong></label><br />
                <TEXTAREA ROWS=4 COLS=32 name="mensaje" class="inputs" id="texto" tabindex="2" style="width:280px;height:142px;" maxlength="600" minlength="10" required onpaste="return false" placeholder="Mensaje..."></TEXTAREA><br>
                <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Enviar" name="entrar">

    </fieldset>
    </form>
    </div>
<!-- Popup Div Ends Here -->
</div>
<!-- Display Popup Button -->
        </div>
    <?php } // fin while ?>
    La funcion contacto1() abre el popup del formulario

        function contacto1() {
    document.getElementById('abc1').style.display = "block";
    }
```